# validation in entity classes

Tags: php, oop, validation

Let's say I have an entity class like this:

```
class car
{
  private $price;
  private $color;

  public __get($name){ ... }
  public __set($name, $value){ ... }
  ...
}
```

and a manager class like this:

```
class CarDealer
{
  private $db;

  public __construct(IDatabase $db) {...}
  public sell(Car $car) {...}
  public insert(Car $car) {...}
  ...
}
```

The question is how can I validate a car's properties? I can do this in the setter method of the car class by checking with `if` statements.

But I think, if there is already a validation service, Symfony\Component\Validator, I should use this. Here, I cannot decide where the validator service comes from.

a) I can depend on this validator and use, by taking it as a parameter of the constructor of the car class. But this injection, injection into an entity is said to be a bad idea. is this true?

b) I can directly instantiate a validator object in the constructor of the car class. But this time, the dependency will be hidden.  this is also a bad approach, right?

c) in view of injecting something to manager classes is fine, I can validate entities in the manager class. But again, this is a bad design, this responsibility is not the manager's, but the entity's itself. right?

What is the best, or conventional way to validate an entity?

### More explanation

The following approach hides the dependency to the `Validator` class, as far as I know. So this is a bad one, right?

```
class car
{
  private $price;
  private $color;

  public __get($name){ ... }
  public setPrice($price} {
    $validator = new Validator();
    $validator->assert($price, '...some constraint...');
  }
  ...
}
```

And this is also bad because the car class depends on something which is not directly related its entity, right?

```
class car
{
  private $price;
  private $color;

  private $validator;

  public __construct(Validator $validator){
    $this->validator = $validator;
  }

  public __get($name){ ... }
  ....
  public setPrice($price} {
    $this->validator->assert($price, '...some constraint...');
  }
  ...
}
```

So, how can I validate prices with an external service?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use simple accessors (getPrice/setPrice) instead of magic and then you can validate values directly in setters.

a - not, but not always handy in case of entities.
b - yes, any logic in constructor is a bad idea.
c - yes, "manager" name for class it's already a bad sign (more about it: [1](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-class-does-too-much/), [2](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontNameClassesObjectManagerHandlerOrData)), and your class will quickly blowed up by all validations of entities.

Comment: indeed, in the getPrice() method I can validate any given price. But how? If I choose to validate by native language condition structures such as "if price>X and x<price", this is okay. Otherwise, validating by a validator service makes me confusing. I do not know how to get this service. by a dependency container, or instantiating in getPrice() ?

Comment: Better - with dependency injection.